# Не работает валидация в модальном окне

Tags: php, javascript, html

Привет!Мне нужно сделать валидацию формы на JS но у меня не работает вообще скрипт.Посмотрите кому не сложно и скажите где я ошибся.

```
div class="simple-modal">
                  <script type="text/javascript">
                  function validateForm()
                                       {
                                       var x=document.forms["form-modal-call"]["phone"].value;

                                       if (x.length < 9)
                                       {
                                       alert("Не верно введен телефон");
                                        return false;

                                       }
                                       }
                  </script>
                    <h2>Оставьте Ваш телефон <small> и наш менеджер перезвонит, чтобы забронировать разработку проекта.<br><span class="projects-counter form-projects-counter"></span></small></h2>
                    <form name="form-modal-call" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" class="simple-form calculation-form" data-type="1 - Заказать обратный звонок" id="form-call">
                        <input type="hidden" name="type_form" value="Заказать обратный звонок">

                        <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '' ;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : '' ;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : '' ;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_term']) ? $_GET['utm_term'] : '' ;?>">
                        <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : '' ;?>">

                        <input type="text" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" class="phone-mask" name="phone"/>
                        <button type="submit" class="btn white-bg btn-recall"><span>Заказать звонок сейчас</span></button>
                    </form>
                </div>
```

Comment: `getElementById` - вот здесь. "не работает вообще" - приучайтесь в таких случаях первым делом смотреть  в консоль браузера

Comment: Изменил,но не работает.

Comment: Изменил код в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Все работает.

```js
function validateForm() {
  var x = document.forms["form-modal-call"]["phone"].value;
  console.log(x);
  if (x.length < 9) {
    alert("Неверно введен телефон");
    return false;

  }
}
```

```html
<h2>Оставьте Ваш телефон, <small> и наш менеджер перезвонит, чтобы забронировать разработку проекта.<br><span class="projects-counter form-projects-counter"></span></small></h2>
<form name="form-modal-call" action="#" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm();" class="simple-form calculation-form" data-type="1 - Заказать обратный звонок" id="form-call">
  <input type="hidden" name="type_form" value="Заказать обратный звонок">

  <input type="hidden" name="utm_source" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_source']) ? $_GET['utm_source'] : '' ;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_medium" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_medium']) ? $_GET['utm_medium'] : '' ;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_campaign" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_campaign']) ? $_GET['utm_campaign'] : '' ;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_term" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_term']) ? $_GET['utm_term'] : '' ;?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="utm_content" value="<?php echo isset($_GET['utm_content']) ? $_GET['utm_content'] : '' ;?>">

  <input type="text" placeholder="+7 (___) ___-__-__" class="phone-mask" name="phone" />
  <button type="submit" class="btn white-bg btn-recall"><span>Заказать звонок сейчас</span></button>
</form>
```